# TimerTask/Handler запускаются только 1 раз

Tags: android, база-данных, service, cursor

Мне нужно, что-бы в сервисе `TimerTask` или `Handler` работали постоянно. Но когда я запускаю программу, они срабатывают только 1 раз. Может у меня где-то ошибка? Вот мой код с использованием `Handler`

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
DB2 db;
Cursor cursor;
Calendar x = Calendar.getInstance();
int y = x.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int m = x.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int d = x.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int h = x.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int min = x.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int s = x.get(Calendar.SECOND);
Handler handler;
NotificationManager nm;
int l, p, a, i, month, hours, minutes, seconds, m22, d22, v, g, t;
int[] k = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

class UpdateTimeTask extends TimerTask{
public void run(){
MS2.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        db.open();
        cursor = db.getAllData();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int d110 = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("day"));     //here it should do some manipulations with every item in DB.

                if (m22 == 0)
                    if (d22 == 0)
                        if (v == 0)
                            if (g == 0)
                                not();
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());//takes next item

        }cursor.close();
    }
});

}
}
private void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
handler.post(runnable);
}

public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
handler = new Handler();
nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}

public void not() {
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, TEST2.class);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!");
int mNotificationId = 001;
NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0,
            resultIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
db = new DB2(this);
db.open();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Running ", 1).show();
timer.schedule(new UpdateTimeTask(), 0, 1000);

return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
// TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

Это мой код с использованием `TimerTask`

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
DB2 db;
Cursor cursor;
Calendar x = Calendar.getInstance();
int y = x.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int m = x.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int d = x.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int h = x.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int min = x.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int s = x.get(Calendar.SECOND);
private Handler handler = new Handler();
NotificationManager nm;
int l, p, a, i, month, hours, minutes, seconds, m22, d22, v, g, t;
int[] k = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

private void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
handler.post(runnable);
}

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    db.open();
    cursor = db.getAllData();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            int d110 = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("day"));
            if (m22 == 0)
                if (d22 == 0)
                    if (v == 0)
                        if (g == 0)
                            not();

        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());//takes next item
        cursor.close();
    }
    handler.postDelayed(this, 30000);
}

};


public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 30000);
nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}
public void not() {
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, TEST2.class);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Hello World!");
int mNotificationId = 001;
NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this,
                0,
                resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 30000);
db = new DB2(this);
db.open();

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Running ", 1).show();
return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
// TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, или вы запостили подряд два эдентичных куска кода?..

Comment: нет. 1 с использованием handler, 2 - timer

Comment: в самой таске (Runnable) нужно заново шедулить ее же.